# c# - how can I read a specific line from a HTML page

Tags: c#

I have a HTML page with 2 lines. The 2 lines are regarding an update ,but this update can be downloaded only by a specific user.
Basically the HTML file contains:

```
beast
1.11
```

the 1st line is the user and the 2nd is the version.There are no HTML headers or other lines.

- Now my problem is,that I really have no idea how to read just the **2nd** line

A text document can be easily manipulated by:

```
File.ReadLines("Text.txt").ElementAt(1);
```

Is there a similar command wich can be used for reading an HTML file line by line?

HUGE thanks for any reply!!!!

Comment: That's not even valid HTML .. there is probably a *different* question here, somewhere .. ask that one.

Comment: Seconded - Is the *output* of the HTML two lines? Otherwise I don't understand how that's HTML.

Comment: I would not that the code sample that "reads a specific line" actually reads in *every* line, and then goes through them one by one until it reaches the one you wanted.

Comment: yes,I need to read the output

Answer (score 2):

You can use that same exact code to read HTML.
HTML files are ordinary text files that happen to contain HTML tags.

If you want to *parse* the HTML tags, use HTML Agility Pack (on NuGet).